# Can't use global shorcuts for Python applications

Tags: bash, osx, python

I'm using bash on a Mac. My problem is every time I try to run an installed Python application I just get a message that the command can't be found. Like so:

```
-bash: gcloud: command not found
```

Doesn't matter if I'm installing with pip or with the installer script.

Answer (score 0):

My guess it that you are trying to run the Python library by giving the name in your shell like this:

```
gcloud
```

According to this link [gcloud getting started](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-python/latest/), `gcloud` (the Python library) can be used inside a Python script and not standalone.

gcloud SDK can be installed (on Mac) following this link [Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstart-mac-os-x).